# Remove a single border from the path

Tags: inkscape, path, borders

How do I remove my upper and bottom borders without changing the shape of my path? When I try to do it with Node tool's `Delete segment between two non-endpoint nodes`, it messed up the path.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the path. Let one of the copies have only a stroke with no fill. Let the other have only a fill with no stroke. Split and edit the stroke only version. To get the stroke to end at the edge of the fill at the breaking point use butt cap stroke style. See this comparison between round and butt stroke caps:

[image]

Make a group to keep all three parts together.